# Flyway with multiple databases connections

Tags: ant, hudson, flyway

I'm trying to use flyway on a complex ERP with multiple databases, but I didn't find any hint to make it runs.
I'm using an ant script together with Hudson to build the whole system.
So, I created a migrate.xml file with the contents below and call the script multiple times at tasks the below.
However, the task runs with any errors only once. 
If I call the task twice, an exception is thrown.
Any idea to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
--exception
BUILD FAILED
/home/raphael/Development/ufpb/sig/sig-migration-fly-way/build.xml:6: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/raphael/Development/ufpb/sig/sig-migration-fly-way/migrate.xml:27: Flyway Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null source
    at java.util.EventObject.<init>(EventObject.java:38)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.BuildEvent.<init>(BuildEvent.java:93)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.fireMessageLogged(Project.java:2351)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.log(Project.java:492)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.ant.AntLog.debug(AntLog.java:42)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.dbsupport.DbSupportFactory.createDbSupport(DbSupportFactory.java:59)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.execute(Flyway.java:1159)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway.info(Flyway.java:967)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.ant.MigrateTask.doExecuteWithMigrationConfig(MigrateTask.java:157)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.ant.AbstractMigrationLoadingTask.doExecute(AbstractMigrationLoadingTask.java:271)
    at com.googlecode.flyway.ant.AbstractFlywayTask.execute(AbstractFlywayTask.java:329)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)

--task
  <target name="test">
     <ant antfile="migrate.xml">
      <property name="dir" value="sigaa"/>
      <property name="database" value="demo_development"/>
     </ant>
  </target>   

---migrate.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="migrations" default="deploy" basedir="." xmlns:flyway="antlib:com.googlecode.flyway.ant">

   <path id="flyway.classpath">
       <!-- include all jars containing jdbc drivers -->
       <!-- include all jars and directories containing sql migrations -->
       <!-- include all jars and directories containing compiled java migrations -->
        <fileset dir="lib">
            <include name="*.jar" />
    </fileset>       
   </path>

   <taskdef uri="antlib:com.googlecode.flyway.ant"
            resource="com/googlecode/flyway/ant/antlib.xml" />

    <property name="flyway.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="flyway.initOnMigrate" value="true"/>
    <property name="flyway.validateOnMigrate" value="true"/>
    <property name="flyway.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/${database}"/>
    <property name="flyway.user" value="***"/>
    <property name="flyway.password" value="****"/> 
    <property name="flyway.table" value="schema_version_${dir}"/>               
    <property name="flyway.locations" value="filesystem:db/migrations/${dir}"/>

    <target name="migrate">
        <flyway:migrate />
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" depends="migrate">
        <flyway:info />
    </target>                       
</project>
```

Comment: It looks like an issue deep down within Ant's logging. Try again without Hudson in the mix, and let me know what the results are.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in class com.googlecode.flyway.ant.AntLog of flyway-ant project, because of log method of org.apache.tools.ant.Project class. On the second time of execution, the code antProject.getThreadTask(Thread.currentThread()) returns null and the error occurs.
I put an if statement to solve the problem like the code below

```
if (task != null)
    antProject.log(task, message, null, Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
else
    antProject.log(message, null, Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
```

Comment: I disagree. If you are inside Flyway code, you are always within the context of a task. Hence task should never be null. Somehow it seems Hudson is messing with the Ant internals here.

Comment: Just submitted an issue about the very same behaviour (http://code.google.com/p/flyway/issues/detail?id=487). There is a bug in Flyway's logging infrastructure.